# Хранить и редактировать данные из MYSQL или ФАЙЛА в php

Tags: php

Исходник: TXT файл. В нем 800 000 строк.
Работа: Берется 1 строка с удалением и сохраняется файл.
**ВОПРОС:** Что лучше использовать для такой задачи - MYSQL или обычный текстовый файл на сервере? Решается все через php.

Comment: Про удаление более подробно расскажите. Удалить строку из файла - это значит создать новый файл, переписать в него все строки, кроме удаляемой и переименовать в исходное имя. Это очень напряжно. Может не надо все таки удалять ? А например задача разбить строки из входного файла в несколько выходных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быстрее будет, если сделать через файл. Вот накидал готовый код.

```
    <?php
$row_number = 0;    //номер строки которую удаляем
$file_out = file("keys.txt"); // Считываем весь файл в массив

//записываем нужную строку  в файл
echo $strok=$file_out[$row_number];

echo "$file_out[$row_number]"; 
//удаляем записаную строчку
unset($file_out[$row_number]);

//записали остачу в файл
file_put_contents("keys.txt", implode("", $file_out));
?>
```

Comment: Как раз то, что нужно. Идеально вписывается в мою ситуацию.